# Explanation for exponential coordinate of rotation

Tags: motion, rotation, screw-theory

[image]

From figure above, suppose a three-dimensional vector $p(0)$ is rotated by an angle $\theta$ about the fixed rotation axis $\omega$ to $p(\theta)$. Here we assume all quantities are expressed fixed frame coordinates and $\Vert \omega \Vert = 1$. This rotation can be achieved by imagining that $p(0)$ is subject to a rotation about $\omega$ at a constant rate of $1$ rad/sec, from time $t = 0$ to $t = \theta$. Let $p(t)$ denote this path. The velocity of $p(t)$, denoted $\dot{p}$, is then given by

$$
\begin{equation}
\dot{p} = \omega \times p
\end{equation}
$$

Please explain in detail as to how to derive the above equation. Thank you.

Comment: is this a school assignment? ... also, using capitals equates to YELLING

Comment: @jsotola It is not a school assignment but I learnt it in my robotics class and I am finding it difficult to derive (1) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that

1. $p(0)$ travels along an arc of the circle of radius $r = \Vert p \Vert \sin(\phi)$ centered at a point on the axis of $\omega$; and
2. the velocity $\dot{p}$ is perpendicular to the arc of the circle; and
3. (from the definition) $\omega = \dot{\theta} u$, where $u$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane of rotation.

Now we try to relate $\dot{p}$ to the known quantities.

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\Vert \dot{p} \Vert &= r\dot{\theta} & \text{(from 2.)}\\
&= (\Vert p \Vert \sin(\phi))\dot{\theta} & \text{(from 1.)}\\
&= \Vert p \Vert \Vert \omega \Vert \sin(\phi) & \text{(from 3.)}
\end{align}
$$
From the above, we can therefore conclude that $\dot{p} = \omega \times p$.

Answer (score 4):

The author expects a background that includes a course in physics or mechanics where this equation is taught. When that is the case, this equation gives you instantaneous velocity of a particle (point) moving on a circular path.

The $\times$ in $\dot{p} = \omega \times p$ is the cross product. (This may already be obvious to you, it's hard to tell from the question).

The vector result of the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) will always be perpendicular to the plane that the operand vectors lie in. The magnitude of the vector result will be $\Vert \omega \Vert\Vert p \Vert  \sin(\phi)$. How to do the cross product operation is in the wikipedia article.

A break down of the equation that may answer your question is [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Particle_in_three_dimensions).

For a book that does a good job teaching working in exponential coordinates I highly recommend [A mathematical introduction to robotic manipulation by Murray, Li, and Sastry](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf).